# How to open a .json file in a certain namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

It should be easy to load a file using a namespace, but I cannot seem to generate the url to it. The file is located in the same directory as `MyClass`, where it is called from.

```
<?php namespace Mynamespace\Subnamespace;

class MyClass {
  public function getFile() {
    $fileLocation = 'myfile.json'; // file is located next to this class in Mynamespace\Subnamespace\file.json
    return file_get_contents( $fileLocation );
  }
}
```

The closest solution I found is using the method `getFileName()` in a `ReflectionClass` of `MyClass`. But that returns the full url including the class MyClass.php file. And using a regExp on that seems overkill, since there is probably an easier solution.

If a namespace can somehow be converted into a valid url, that should do the trick.

How should file.json be retreived?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not have a central location you write these to? It would be a lot easier to maintain this if you did that.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes I tried using __NAMESPACE__. That returns the name of the namespace ( Mynamespace\Subnamespace ). But my `file_get_contents()` funtion returns an error if I generate a namespace like that `Warning: file_get_contents(Mynamespace\Subnamespace\myfile.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory..`. So apparently I need the actual url and not the namespace.

Comment: What is the ACTUAL full path to the JSON file?

Comment: @Machavity The json file only stores some values specifically related to the `MyClass` class. So it seemed a good idea to store them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use namespaces for JSON files. But since it is in the same directory as the class you should be able to use `__DIR__`

```
<?php namespace Mynamespace\Subnamespace;

class MyClass {
  public function getFile() {
    $fileLocation = 'myfile.json';
    return file_get_contents( __DIR__ . PATH_SEPARATOR . $fileLocation );
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I assumed wrongly that __DIR__ would refer to the path the code is initially called from, I was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with [get_class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)

```
<?php namespace Mynamespace\Subnamespace;

class MyClass {
  public function getFile() {
    // Will have backslashes so str_replace if this is a Unix environment
    $path = str_replace('\\', '/', get_class($this));
    $fileLocation = $path . '/myfile.json'; // Mynamespace/Subnamespace/myfile.json
    return file_get_contents( $fileLocation );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just this:

```
$fileLocation = __NAMESPACE__ . '\myfile.json';
```

See [PHP: namespace keyword and __NAMESPACE__ constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php#language.namespaces.nsconstants).

But since you state "*file is located next to this class in Mynamespace\Subnamespace\file.json*" then you can just use the full path to the current file:

```
$fileLocation = __DIR__ . '\myfile.json';  // or  dirname(__FILE__)
```

See [PHP: Magic Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).